# Having problem with npm package called "canvas"

Tags: node.js, npm, canvas

Here is my code:

```
if(data.queryresult.pods[0]){
  ctx.fillText(data.queryresult.pods[0].title)
  var img = await loadImage(data.queryresult.pods[0].subpods[0].img.src)
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  let file = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'output.png')
  message.channel.send({
    files: [file]
  })
}
```

My problem is that `ctx.fillText(data.queryresult.pods[0].title)` does not write anything. How can I fix this?

Link to npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, in the function `ctx.fillText()` you are supposed to pass three arguments (example from the page you attached):

```
ctx.fillText('Hello World', 50, 80)
```

Just like in `ctx.drawImage()`

Try adding those two arguments, it should start working.